# Convert String to 24 Hour time format in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, time

I'm having a problem with converting some string short time values to a 24 hour time format.

In the script I have the following foreach loop to parse each line of data from a `csv`:

```
Foreach ($Line in $Data) {
    $command.CommandText=$SQLCommandPre+ `
        "'"+$line."Reference" `
        +"','"+$line."Date" `
        +"','"$line."Business Hour".SubString(0,8) `
        +"','"+"{0:f2}" -f ($line."Total"/2) `
    +"','"+"{0:f0}" -f ($line."Number"/2) `
    +"')"
    [void] $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

For Example my source data is:

```
0101,8/19/2012,12:00 AM - 12:59 AM,241.83,21
```

Currently in the script it is just grabbing 12am but I need to convert to 00:00. I've tried using the following but it has no affect to the query powershell creates:

```
"{0:HH:mm}" -f ($line."Business Hour".SubString(0,8))
```

I've been unable to locate a hit of another method to reach my goal.

Comment: Do you just want to get the time eg 2:00 PM and convert it to 14:00 for example ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you convert the retrieved string to a [DateTime] object before trying to format it e.g.:

```
C:\PS> "{0:HH:mm}" -f [datetime]'12:00 AM'
00:00
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought I'd tried this already but I guess I typo'd it.

Answer (score 0):

There will be multiple ways to accomplish this. Here is how I would probably do it:

```
$test = '0101,8/19/2012,12:00 AM - 12:59 AM,241.83,21'
([dateTime]$test.Split(',')[2].Split('-')[0]).ToString('HH:mm')
```

you can tweak how to get the substring if you want. In a case like this I prefer split over .SubString() since it would be more tolerant of changes in string length.